# $C^\infty$ function which is constant on two intervals and implicitly defined inbetween

Tags: calculus, analysis

My textbook states without further reference that there exists a $C^\infty$ function $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $|\alpha'(t)| < K$ where $K>2$, and

$$
\alpha(t) = \begin{cases}
 0 & t \ge 1 \\
 1 & t \le \tfrac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

It seems intuitive that it exists, but I wonder if there is an explicit form or a simple proof for its existence. I was thinking about an integrated gaussian function between $\tfrac12 < t <1 $, but since the domain is bounded, I couldn't find a way to work it out.

Comment: You can hand craft one from the smooth function $f$ defined by $$x\mapsto f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\leq 0\\ e^{-1/x}&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}$$ by means of integration and mulitplying them together. This is nicely explained in Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

Comment: Great ;) that is indeed well explained